# Error everytime I open Terminal I get "zsh: command not found"

Tags: macos, terminal

Even basic commands like 'pwd' or 'ls' I get the same error message. I'm completely lost, been looking across all websites looking for a solution. I've found commands that temporarily fix the problem like "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH"

but as soon as I close and start a new terminal the same issue happens again when I reopen it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your PATH (where all your commands are located) has been corrupted. Could you perhaps try `echo $PATH` to see whether it is what you expect?.

If it is not, you may want to have a look at your `zshrc` for any suspicious lines. You can do so with: `open -a TextEdit ~/.zshrc`

If this gives you an error, you hay have to do: `touch ~/.zshrc` first.

Delete the lines you think may be causing the problem.

For a quick fix, add `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` to the end of your `zshrc` that you just opened using TextEdit. This will reset the PATH variable to the macOS default.